# Solved - Combine multiple render regions with different sampling values

Tags: rendering, resolution, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to render twice the same scene, the first time with few samples, the second time with more samples but cropped for faster rendering.
Then I want to combine them in the compositor in a blank scene.

The problem is that the cropping doesn't work even though I checked "Render region" in the Output properties tab:
[image: text]

And if I render from the cropped scene, everything gets cropped:
[image: text]

Is there any way to selectively activate the cropping?

Comment: How do you 'Activate' the cropping?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i do not understand your compositing at all because with fac == 1 in alpha over you will only get the 2nd render for further compositing. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @CoolCoder I just used CTRL+B

Comment: @Community I was trying to get more rays on some parts of my image without recomputing everything.
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/k4vxBJ3/test.jpg">

Comment: @Chris yes indeed it is intended as I the cropped rendering is transparent apart from the rendered zones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I turned on 'render single layer' in the view layer proprieties and it worked:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Nick ! By ticking 'Render single layer' and by using the Film icon on the Render nodes instead of pressing F12, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was trying to get a faster rendering of my image with few rays in general and more rays only for certain areas. With the solution provided by Nick, I'm twice faster globally with a perfect definition for my point of interest.

Here is an example, voluntarily extreme :
[image: Composite image]

[image: Nodes]